# Email failed when sending attachment

Tags: php, codeigniter

I just moved my website from one hosting company to another. But in the process, my email function doesn't work if I send with an attachment.

This is from the debugger:

```
Unable to send email using PHP mail(). Your server might not be configured to send mail using this method.
User-Agent: CodeIgniter
Date: Sat, 1 Jun 2013 03:01:46 +0700
From: "My name" 
Return-Path: 
Reply-To: "info@mysite.org" 
X-Sender: info@mysite.org
X-Mailer: CodeIgniter
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
Message-ID: <51a901aa74a21@mysite.org>
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="B_ATC_51a901aa74aa0"


=?iso-8859-1?Q?Email_Test?=
This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
Your email application may not support this format.

--B_ATC_51a901aa74aa0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_51a901aa74a67"

--B_ALT_51a901aa74a67
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Testing the email class.


--B_ALT_51a901aa74a67
Content-Type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

Testing the email class.

--B_ALT_51a901aa74a67--

--B_ATC_51a901aa74aa0
Content-type: image/png; name="screenshot.png"
Content-Disposition: attachment;
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
```

This is my code

```
$config['set_newline'] = "\r\n";
$config['mailtype'] = 'html';
$config['charset'] = 'iso-8859-1';
$config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;

$this->email->initialize($config);

$this->email->from('me@mysite.org', 'Me');
$this->email->to('someone@someone.com'); 

$this->email->subject('Email Test');
$this->email->message('Testing the email class.'); 
$this->email->attach('screenshot.png'); //I put it on root directory of CI 

$this->email->send();
echo $this->email->print_debugger();
```

But if I send email with attachments using a library outside CI, it's working. Actually, my solution right now is to make a helper for sending mail not using the CI library. But if there's any way I could still using CI library, it would be great.

Comment: Does it work if you comment out the line `$this->email->attach('screenshot.png');`? Or to put it differently: Is it really the attachment that causes the problem or is it how CodeIgniter's email functionality is configured?

Comment: yap...if i don't attach any file, it will be working

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to solve it by changing the email.php file in system/libraries folder of codeigniter

```
var $protocol = "smtp"; // mail/sendmail/smtp
var $smtp_host = "localhost";  // SMTP Server.
```

The problem seemed to be the mail protocol in the first line above.

You may also have to add username and the password in teh next two lines if you have those setup

```
var $smtp_user = "my_username";  // SMTP Username
var $smtp_pass = "my_password";  // SMTP Password
```

Comment: i also facing some problem but i use sendmail and its fine
$config['protocol'] = 'sendmail';

Comment: try and change it to smtp from sendmail. See if that solves your problem